# Process to convert simple Python script into Windows executable

Tags: python, packaging, compilation, py2exe, software-distribution

I wrote a script that will help a Windows user in her daily life. I want to simply send her the .exe and not ask her to install python, dlls or have to deal with any additional files.

I've read plenty of the stackoverflow entries regarding compiling Python scripts into executable files. I am a bit confused as there are many options but some seem dated (no updates since 2008) and none were simple enough for me not to be asking this right now after a few hours spent on this.

I'm hoping there's a better, up-to-date way to do this.

I looked into:

- [pylunch](http://code.google.com/p/pylunch/)
- [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/)
- [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/)
- [py2app](http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk/doc/index.html) (only for Mac)
- [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/)
- [bbfreeze](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bbfreeze/)

but either I couldn't get them to work or couldn't understand how to get the result I need. The closest I got was with py2exe but it still gave me the MSVCR71.dll

I would appreciate a step-by-step answer as I was also unable to follow some of the tweaking answers here that require some prior understanding of how to use py2exe or some of the other tools.

I'm using Python 2.5 as one of the modules is only available for that version.

Comment: *most* of the time you can ignore the MSVCR dll, I don't distribute it with my application and haven't heard any any errors (key point being they may have happened, and I just haven't had a report of it :))

Answer (score 33):

PyInstaller will create a single-file executable if you use the `--onefile` option (though what it actually does is extracts then runs itself).

There's a simple PyInstaller tutorial [here](http://bytes.com/topic/python/insights/579554-simple-guide-using-pyinstaller).  If you have any questions about using it, please post them...

Comment: Its a lot better recently. You can just type `pip install pyinstaller` to install it and `pyinstaller -w yourpythonscript.py` to compile it to an exe.

Answer (score 13):

Using py2exe, include this in your setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1}},
    windows = [{'script': "YourScript.py"}],
    zipfile = None,
)
```

then you can run it through command prompt / Idle, both works for me. Hope it helps

Answer (score 13):

i would recommend going to http://sourceforge.net/projects/py2exe/files/latest/download?source=files to download py2exe. Then make a python file named setup.py. 
Inside it, type

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(console=['nameoffile.py'])
```

Save in your user folder
Also save the file you want converted in that same folder

Run window's command prompt
type in `setup.py install py2exe`

It should print many lines of code...

Next, open the dist folder.

Run the `exe` file.

If there are needed files for the program to work, move them to the folder

Copy/Send the dist folder to person.

Optional: Change the name of the dist folder

Hope it works!:)

Comment: This is awesome, I hade my scripts organised in several folders that were using each other, but this method picked up all of the dependencies. I've trued pyinstaller-2.0 and that didn't pickup dependencies causing the resulting executable to print errors related to importing the dependencies.

Comment: I tried to use this method but i didn't work. When i typed the info in command prompt it just ran my script

Answer (score 9):

I would join @Nicholas in recommending [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) (with the `--onefile` flag), but *be warned*: do **not** use the "latest release", PyInstaller 1.3 -- it's *years* old.  Use the "pre-release" 1.4, download it [here](http://www.pyinstaller.org/changeset/latest/trunk?old_path=%2F&format=zip) -- or even better the code from the [svn repo](http://www.pyinstaller.org/export/latest/trunk/) -- install SVN and run `svn co http://svn.pyinstaller.org/trunk pyinstaller`.

As @Nicholas implies, dynamic libraries cannot be *run* from the same file as the rest of the executable -- but fortunately they can be *packed* together with all the rest in a "self-unpacking" executable that will unpack itself into some temporary directory as needed; PyInstaller does a good job at this (and at many other things -- `py2exe` is more popular, but `pyinstaller` in my opinion is preferable in all other respects).

Comment: I have looked up to the links you gave here, they are not available any more. Does `PyIstaller` work on more than a file and with `Python 2.7` too?

Comment: PyInstaller now lives on GitHub, it's up to version 2.1, and supports Python 2.7 (among other releases). Of course "it works on more than one file" (as input) but the whole point is producing a single file as output. See https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki and links therefrom.

Answer (score 6):

1) Get py2exe from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/py2exe/files/py2exe/0.6.9/), according to your Python version.

2) Make a file called "setup.py" in the same folder as the script you want to convert, having the following code:

> ```
> from distutils.core import setup
> import py2exe
> setup(console=['myscript.py']) #change 'myscript' to your script
> ```

3) Go to command prompt, navigate to that folder, and type:

> ```
> python setup.py py2exe
> ```

4) It will generate a "dist" folder in the same folder as the script. This folder contains the .exe file.

Comment: Could you possibly delete this answer since it's a duplicate of Bob's answer below posted 2 years earlier.

Answer (score 2):

you may want to see if your app can run under IronPython. If so, you can compile it to an exe 
http://www.codeplex.com/IronPython

Comment: If you use IronPython (I'm developing a commercial software in it be aware that it requires .NET Framework 2.0 )

Answer (score 1):

You can create executable from python script using [NSIS](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Download) (Nullsoft scriptable install system). Follow the below steps to convert your python files to executable.

- Download and install [NSIS](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Download) in your system.
- Compress the folder in the `.zip` file that you want to export into the executable.
- Start `NSIS` and select `Installer based on ZIP file`. Find and provide a path to your compressed file.
- Provide your `Installer Name` and `Default Folder` path and click on <kbd>Generate</kbd> to generate your `exe` file.
- Once its done you can click on <kbd>Test</kbd> to test executable or <kbd>Close</kbd> to complete the process.
- The executable generated can be installed on the system and can be distributed to use this application without even worrying about installing the required python and its packages.

For a video tutorial follow: [How to Convert any Python File to `.EXE`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UZX5kH72Yx4&t=340s)

Answer (score -4):

You could create an installer for you EXE file by:
1. Press WinKey + R
2. Type "iexpress" (without quotes) into the run window
3. Complete the wizard for creating the installation program.
4. Distribute the completed EXE.

Comment: This is not correct