# standalone Python application

Tags: python

I need some simple examples and tutorials for creating stand-alone python application. I've never do such a thing, so any help is needed. 
More precisely, I have one class - SVGViewer, with one argument - full path to .svg file, and I need it to be standalone and somehow to be able to open .svg files. Any suggestions for that would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your definition of "standalone"? Every Python script is standalone. Do you want to make a "full program", e.g. an .exe in Windows or something?

Comment: sorry for that... yes, I want .exe

Comment: @Aleksander In that case take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136837/process-to-convert-simple-python-script-into-windows-executable (i.e. use py2exe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check how other people do "standalone" SVG viewers in Python.

- http://code.google.com/p/svgfig/
- http://code.google.com/p/svg2rlg/

I guess you can also use [ReportLab](http://www.reportlab.com/software/opensource/) to generate convert the SVG to some bitmap.

Comment: I doubt OPs question is actually specific to SVG viewers though.

Comment: You missunderstood me.. What I wanted is to create .exe file for my program, not to run it from Eclipse, as I do now.

Comment: Ah, then you have to take a look at the [py2exe project](http://www.py2exe.org/).