# Python Script to Windows Executable - GUI edition

Tags: python, user-interface, installation

I'm already aware of [converting a python script to an executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136837/process-to-convert-simple-python-script-into-windows-executable) that **can be run through the command line** but I was hoping somebody would know of an easy method to have this script run with a GUI installer without having to write my own GUI code.

I'm asking because my script asks for some user input (location of certain folders, personal info, etc.) before installing for it to function and it would look a lot better if I had a GUI for it.

Comment: I'm really not sure if you want to generate a Windows installer (for which you can use Installer generators like Inno Setup, NSIS, etc) or add GUI to your command-line script (for which you can use a GUI library like WxPython, PyGTK, PyQT, PySide, etc).

Comment: So you want a GUI installer for your non-GUI Python-based .exe program? You could use [EasyGui](http://easygui.sourceforge.net/) to write a relatively simple Python program with a GUI and then convert that into an executable, too.