# make an excutable Gui for data analysis in python

Tags: python, r, python-2.7

I have a data set and would like to write a python code which analyses these data and represents the  diagrams (mostly histograms) in a [image: GUI] (like `glueviz`). 
In the final step, I would like to combine the GUI and the code into an executable file in a folder so that the final user does not need any python.

In case of R I would use `shiny` for such a problem, however one cannot publish/deploy shiny and R easily to one executable stand alone file!

In case of python, which [GUI](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming) can I use? The GUI may look like [shiny](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/) or `glueviz`.
At the end of day, how can I make an executable file (in Windows) from the calculation engine and the GUI which runs locally?
*GUI + calculation engine (python) -> one_file.exe*

Please Note, I know the plot packages in python. There are couple of GUI packages in python too. However, the question is

Is there any 
GUI (with the possibility to show graphics )+calculation engine (python),  both integrated in each other?

Comment: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a software tool or library are off topic for Stackoverflow.* If you search, there's plenty of resources for making a Python exe. If you just want to plot stuff, matplotlib or pyplot would be a good start

Comment: @cricket_007 you did not even understand the question!

Comment: What did I not understand? I said `matplotlib` or `pyplot`.... If anything its a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136837/process-to-convert-simple-python-script-into-windows-executable That question you linked to is 3 years old. The guidelines for StackOverflow posts change over the years

Comment: That's *not* an *"Explonation"*, it's just an assertion. Be specific about how the existing resources fail to answer your precise question.

Comment: @cricket_007 the programs you suggested I know but I am not looking for a plot package even not for a GUI standalone, I am looking for a package similar to shiny with a local publishing possibility.

Comment: @jonrsharpe you may be right and I am sorry about that however, I wish that one reads the question more precisely.

Comment: And I did read the question! "Is there any GUI/tool that does X" is a [recommendation question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393). You linked to the Python wiki for GUI programming, so go read to make a GUI. I linked you to make a EXE. It's possible to combine them. I have no idea what Shiny provides, other than a web app, not an exe. And if you wanted a web app with to show charts, then you'd typically use Javascript to draw on a webpage, which is hosted by a Python web server, not a GUI tool

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks, you are actually right with the java script which is hosted by a Python web server and I thought at the beginning of  a html as a "GUI". But I do not know how :(. I need just a simple example

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks Flask and Django seem to be the most popular

Comment: @cricket_007  thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into `Rinno` package [found on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RInno/index.html).

Information about getting started is found on the [author's webpage](https://www.ficonsulting.com/filabs/RInno), in brief:

> ```
> install.packages("RInno")
> require(RInno)
> RInno::install_inno()
> ```
>
> We put a simple example Shiny app in the package:
>
> ```
> example_app(app_dir = "app")
> ```
>
> A minimal installation can be created using the package defaults with
>   two lines of code:
>
> ```
> create_app(app_name = "myapp", app_dir = "app")
> compile_iss()
> ```
>
> Now, there should be a new directory, app/RInno_installer, in your
>   working directory. ***Double-click the .exe to see how that example app
>   can be installed on your computer***.

Comment: Thanks I know it, however I am looking for a similar solution in Python