# This code is for a chat program help me to make it work on different laptops

Tags: python-3.x

```
#server( the server page and client page should be put in different python pages)
from tkinter import*
import socket #imports the socket library 
import sys
import time
import threading # used to set a timer for recieveing  
window1=Tk()
window1.title("Server page")
window1.geometry('800x800')

background_image=PhotoImage(file="h123.png") #the background picture
background_label =Label(window1, image=background_image)
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)


input_box=Entry(window1, width=90) #masseage text input value
input_box.place(x=19,y=650)

shift_value=Entry(window1,width=5) #shift input value
shift_value.place(x=680,y=700)
shift_lapl=Label(text="Enter The Encryption key",bg='black',fg='white')#shift label
shift_lapl.place(x=620,y=730)

def myfunction(event):#the function for the scroll bar
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"),width=200,height=200)

def encryption(): #The function for encrypting the chat and called when clicked the Encrypt button
    d=input_box.get()
    w=shift_value.get()
    global shift
    global result
    global phrase
    global o
    o=''
    phrase =d
    shift=int(w)
    p=[]
    for character in phrase:
        x = ord(character)

        x = x + shift

        p.append(chr (x))
    for y in p:
        o+=y  
    shift_value.delete(0,100)    
    input_box.delete(0,100)
    input_box.insert(0,(o))

def word(): #Th decryption function used when clicking the Decrypt button 
    global label
    g=label.cget("text")
    f=len(g)
    d=g[11:f]
    l1=[]
    r=''
    for i in d:
        z=ord(i)
        w=z-(int(shift_value.get()))#the value put in the shift box
        l1.append(chr(w))
    for t in l1:
        r+=t
    label=Label(frame,text='Unencrupted: '+r,fg='green')
    label.pack(side=TOP)         
    return 'break'        


def serverc():#servre creation
        global s
        global q
        s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)#TCP connection for sending words in an orderded way
        host = '192.168.56.1'
        print("server will start on host:",host)
        port=8080
        addr=(host,port)
        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)#to allow us reuse the port once again
        s.bind(addr)  #binding to the host and the port written 
        s.listen(10)
        conn,addr=s.accept()
        q=conn

def server_send():#Sending massages and showing it in the chat box(chat_box) 
            v=input_box.get()
            global label
            label = Label(frame, text='This PC: '+v,fg='blue')
            label.pack(side=TOP)#showing the text in the frame in labels
            input_box.delete(0,100)
            message =v
            message = message.encode()
            q.send(message)
            print(message)
            return 'break'
def server_recieve():#recieving massages
    threading.Timer(5.0,server_recieve).start()
    try:
        global label
        incoming_message = q.recv(1024)# the maximum number of bytes of wors that a socket can send or recieve
        incoming_message = incoming_message.decode()
        label = Label(frame, text='Client PC: '+incoming_message,fg='green')
        label.pack(side=TOP)
        return 'break'
    except:
        print(1)
b1=Button(window1,width=5,height=2,text='send',bg='gray',fg='black', command=server_send)#send button
b1.place(x=675,y=640)

B=Button(window1,text="Log in",width=10,height=2 ,bg='white', fg='black', command=serverc)#log in button  
B.place(x=20,y=10)


b2=Button(window1,width=10,height=2,text="Encrypt",fg="white",bg="red", command=encryption)#incrept button
b2.place(x=450,y=700)

b3=Button(window1,width=10,height=2,text="Decrypt",fg="white",bg="blue", command=word)#un incrept button
b3.place(x=140,y=700)


#the new edits

frame = Frame(window1, width=800, height=800)#the chat frame that shows the massages sent and recieved
input_box.bind("<Return>", server_send)
frame.pack()

canvas=Canvas(frame)
framen=Frame(canvas)
myscrollbar=Scrollbar(frame,orient="vertical",command=canvas.xview)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=myscrollbar.set)

myscrollbar.pack(side="left",fill="y")
canvas.pack(side="left")
canvas.create_window((0,0),window=framen,anchor='nw')
framen.bind("<Configure>",myfunction)
myfunction(server_send)

server_recieve()

window1.mainloop()

#the client page  

from tkinter import*
import socket
import sys
import time
import threading
global shift
global result
global phrase
global o
window1=Tk()
window1.title("client page")
window1.geometry('800x800')

background_image=PhotoImage(file="h123.png")
background_label =Label(window1, image=background_image)
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

input_box=Entry(window1, width=90) #masseage text
input_box.place(x=19,y=650)

shift_value=Entry(window1,width=5) #shift value
shift_value.place(x=680,y=700)
shift_lapl=Label(text="Enter The Encryption value")
shift_lapl.place(x=620,y=730)

def myfunction(event):
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"),width=200,height=200)

def encryption():
    d=input_box.get()
    w=shift_value.get()

    o=''
    phrase =d
    shift=int(w)
    p=[]
    for character in phrase:
        x = ord(character)

        x = x + shift

        p.append(chr (x))
    for y in p:
        o+=y  
    shift_value.delete(0,100)    
    input_box.delete(0,100)
    input_box.insert(0,(o))

def word():
    global label
    g=label.cget("text")
    f=len(g)
    d=g[11:f]
    l1=[]
    r=''
    for i in d:
        z=ord(i)
        w=z-(int(shift_value.get()))
        l1.append(chr(w))
    for t in l1:
        r+=t
    label=Label(frame,text='Unencrupted: '+r,fg='blue')
    label.pack(side=TOP)         
    return 'break'

def clientc():#client creation
    global s
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    host ='192.168.56.1'
    port = 8080
    s.connect((host,port))
    print(" Connected to chat server")
import time
def client_recieve():
    threading.Timer(5.0,client_recieve).start()
    try:
        global label
        incoming_message = s.recv(1024)
        incoming_message = incoming_message.decode()
        label=Label(frame,text=('Server PC: '+incoming_message),fg='blue')
        label.pack(side=TOP)
        return 'break'
    except:
        print(1)
def client_send():
        v=input_box.get()
        global label
        label = Label(frame, text='This PC: '+v,fg='green')
        label.pack(side=TOP)        
        input_box.delete(0,100)                
        message = v
        message = message.encode()
        s.send(message)        
        return 'break'                  
b1=Button(window1,width=5,height=2,text='send',bg='gray',fg='black', command=client_send)#send button
b1.place(x=675,y=640)

B=Button(window1,width=10,height=2,text="Log in", bg='white', fg='black', command=clientc)#log in button  
B.place(x=20,y=10)


b2=Button(window1,width=10,height=2,text="Encrypt",fg="white",bg="red", command=encryption)#Encrypt button
b2.place(x=450,y=700)

b3=Button(window1,width=10,height=2,text="Unencrypt",fg="white",bg="blue", command=word)# unencrypt button
b3.place(x=140,y=700)

# the two lapls at the top of screan for messages

#the new edits

frame = Frame(window1, width=300, height=300)
input_box.bind("<Return>", client_send)
frame.pack()

canvas=Canvas(frame)
framen=Frame(canvas)
myscrollbar=Scrollbar(frame,orient="vertical",command=canvas.xview)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=myscrollbar.set)

myscrollbar.pack(side="left",fill="y")
canvas.pack(side="left")
canvas.create_window((0,0),window=framen,anchor='nw')
framen.bind("<Configure>",myfunction)
myfunction(client_send)



client_recieve()  
window1.mainloop()
```

## The software works when running the server page and client page on the same laptop the steps to make it work

1- As you open it click login in the servers page first then in the clients page 
2-start chating normally 
3- when you try to run the client code on a laptop and the server on another the program does not work

Comment: What is your question? (There's a reason SO makes you type a certain number of chars in your question).

Comment: _"help me to make it work on different laptops"_ is not a valid question for stackoverflow. This isn't a free code-writing service.

Answer (score -1):

You need to convert your program to an .exe

A few stackoverflow posts have already documented the process:

[How can I convert a .py to .exe for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570359/how-can-i-convert-a-py-to-exe-for-python)

[Process to convert simple Python script into Windows executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136837/process-to-convert-simple-python-script-into-windows-executable)

Comment: Sorry, this is not the answer.  I posted this before an actual question was asked and wrongly assumed this was the solution.  The solution will be some sort of routing/hosting configuration that I cannot answer.