# Run Tkinter app from desktop

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a python app that uses Tkinter. I would like to run it from my desktop using a shortcut. I have tried using pyinstaller but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running windows, try py2exe. They just expanded their functionality to include python3.

Docs/download: https://pypi.org/project/py2exe/

Comment: This doesn't work. When I run `python setup.py py2exe` it gives me the error `IndexError: tuple index out of range`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136837/process-to-convert-simple-python-script-into-windows-executable

Comment: I looked at that questions but none of the solutions worked

Comment: Have you tried using pyinstaller on a more simple program to see if you can isolate the problem

(e.g. https://mborgerson.com/creating-an-executable-from-a-python-script/)

Comment: It worked for a program that  doesn't use Tkinter but when I try it on the file that does use Tkinter it gives the error `Failed to execute script`

Comment: Tkinter has a lot of cross platform problems (including, but not limited to the fact that it WILL NOT RUN on macosx). There are problems porting Tkinter into executables because the windows remain and do not play nicely with the rest of the application. Consider using easygui or some other gui replacement with better stability.

Comment: Tkinter has no cross platform problems! And it works nicely with the rest of the application. I builded big gui programs with it and without problems.

Comment: You give statements that makes no sense. You didn't give a row of code and how you're using pyinstaller but expect help!?  This platform is not for complaining!