# Can I turn a project file into an Executable file?

Tags: python, html, debugging, compilation

Ive got a python project for a downloadable software I plan on distributing. With .py files, html etc..

Can I compile them into an .exe file? Is there a program I need to download?

Comment: It's a duplicate question. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570359/how-can-i-convert-a-py-to-exe-for-python and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136837/process-to-convert-simple-python-script-into-windows-executable

Answer (score 1):

Yes. without more specific information about the project you could use a program like PyInstaller: http://www.pyinstaller.org to solve the problem you describe.

There is alternatives:
Py2exe: http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial